# Cannot unset or delete a session variable(s) in PHP - Windows server

Tags: php, mysql, session, post, session-variables

First of all, thank you for trying to help for me. :)

We have a Windows Server with PHP sites, mysql databases.
The windows Server version is which doesn't support the .htacces yet, and because of this, we have a rule, thar every 404 error has been reditect to a redirect.php.

Of course, we have a session handlers, which writes to the session table

The problem is with the post and get to niceurl.
I had a solution, to skip this, what is about to set the form action to redirect.php what is set the $_SESSION['lastPost'] variable equal to the $_POST except $_POST['redirect'] what is the redirection url. When i redirected to the url ($_POST['redirect']), i take back the $_SESSION['lastPost'] to the $_POST and unset($_SESSION['lastPost']).

That has been worked perfectly, until the search. Because of the search works with ajax, i had to set the search parameters to the $_SESSION, and after that, i cannot unset the $_SESSION variables. ( Auto Globals is ON on our server too )

If i comment the rows where the $_SESSION values has been set, that works perfectly.

I know that i should not manipulate superglobals, but because of the nice-url, i could not solve otherwise.

I read the most of session unset, and session delete problems, but there is not my solution.
I have session_start();
I tried after the last $_SESSION variable assignment to session_write_close(); but it did not help for me.

redirect.php

```
require_once("###########/inc/session.php"); //that is the right location

if (isset($_POST['redirect']) && !empty($_POST['redirect'])) {

$strRedirect = $_POST['redirect'];

unset($_POST['redirect']);

$_SESSION['lastPost'] = $_POST;

unset($_POST);

redirect(urldecode($strRedirect));

exit();
}
```

search.php

```
require_once("###########/inc/session.php"); //that is the right location

if (isset($_SESSION['lastPost']) && !empty($_SESSION['lastPost'])) {

$_POST = $_SESSION['lastPost'];

unset($_SESSION['lastPost']);

}
```

//if i comment out the session variable assignment below, the $_SESSION['lastPost'] will become null, as it has to, otherwise it will never

```
if (!empty($_POST['job_types_id'])) {

$strJobTypesWhere = "`job_types_id` = '" . (int) $_POST['job_types_id'] . "'";

$_SESSION['job_search'][] = $strJobTypesWhere;

}
```

When i post first time, works fine, the $_POST gets the $_SESSION['lastPost'] value, and after that, when i dump the $_SESSION['lastPost'] is null, and here should be the over...
After a simple refresh on the nice url without posting to the redirect, the $_SESSION['lastPost'] contains the previous $_POST... and i cannot remove

Thanks for trying help for me, and sorry for my english :))

Comment: So the main problem is: if i set any session variable after the unset($_SESSION['lastPost']) the $_SESSION['lastPost'] will not be removed

Comment: After the `unset`, try printing the value of `$_SESSION['lastPost']`, if it doesn't display your code works fine and somewhere it's re-adding it. Try to debug by displaying it wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks :)
I tried already, before and after the unset too, and that works fine.
Before the $_SESSION['lastPost'] is an array, and the $_POST is null, after the $_POST is the same array as the $_SESSION['lastPost'] was, and the $_SESSION['lastPost'] is null, even at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you can assign this way `$_POST = $_SESSION['lastPost'];` because the `$_POST` needs to come only after the form has been actually submitted. Why not use a normal array for this? And not sure if this is useful, but on refresh of page, your POST values will be resubmitted.

Comment: Thanks again :).
Because the redirection's of redirect.php, the $_POST will not beign sent again, just when you click on the submit btn. The form action is point at the redirect.php and that will redirect to the niceurl. The $_POST will get its data only if $_SESSION['lastPost'] has been set, on a page with nice-url. 
The reason why i cannot use a simple array, is the ajax. The designer want to load it on scroll, and than the ajax script should know the search parameters, what whould be in the session, in this time.

Comment: I find the solution.

The Session variable assignment was the wrong.
The string I did want to pass to the session variable has contained illegal characters, like '"%/| . I commented out the assignment, and after that works for me, and I passed the value to the session with bas64_encoded.

the original

>$_SESSION['job_search'][] = $strOrWhere;

The new form

>$_SESSION['job_search'][] = base64_encode($strOrWhere);

And this has solved my problem.
Thank you for everyone who tried to help for me.
Always learn something new.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: Now I changed that a bit, I don't pass the $where straight to the session (independently of the encoding), instead I save the parameters to the session, and the process will work with these, and that will generate the query for itself. It's a bit less nocuous :) - Thanks I Can Has Cheezburger